# Photons don't wiggle perpendicular to their direction of travel do they?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, photons

Every 3D visual explaining a photon shows the photon moving through space (let's say on Z axis), with electric component wiggling up and down on the Y axis, and magnetic component wiggling left and right on X axis (or visa versa for X and Y).

As well as this, it's often stated that the magnetic component wiggles at 90° or perpendicular to the electric component.

Presumably though, these wiggles aren't in space, they are just the electric/magnetic charge values changing over time as the photon travels in a straight line on the Z axis, and they are 90° out of phase with each other, not spacially perpendicular?

Otherwise the photon would have a width and the two components of it would be moving faster than the speed of light due to the wiggling motion.

Is this right? I've looked back through a bunch of my science resources since realising this to see if I just misunderstood the material, but the wiggling in space version is still often the obvious takeaway.

Comment: One of my professors said to instead think of it like a light bulb flying straight that is brightening and dimming as it goes. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is correct. The "wiggle" is just a representation of the oscillation of the electromagnetic field. The photon itself travels in a straight line (as long as it is in a vacuum and far from deep gravity wells).

Answer (score 1):

The plots you have seen are just a way of visualising what is happening to both the strength *and* direction of the electric and magnetic fields associated with the electromagnetic wave. I am guessing you mean an example like the one below.

The fields are defined at points in space (and vary with time) - they have no physical dimension. However they are vector fields, which means they have both a magnitude and direction andchoosing how to represent that is challenging. So frequently what is done is draw two sine waves at right angles to each other and the direction of wave motion. These sine waves represent the magnitude of the electricand magnetic fields, whilst their orientation is telling you in which directions the electric and magnetic fields point - often reinforced by adding arrows whose height represent the magntidue and diection is the field direction.

So nothing is wiggling in physical space - the wiggles represent the changing strength and direction of the electric and magnetic fields along the (straight) path taken by the light.

[image: Typical EM wave image]

Comment: And by "direction", do you just mean that the magnitudes oscillate between negative and positive I guess?

Comment: That is indeed the type of visualisation I'm refering to

Comment: @IronAttorney - yes, once you have defined an axis, then the E-field (and B-field) will simply alternate (in phase) their direction along that axis.